# X,Y.Z axes are way too bigger suddenly

Tags: modeling

Suddenly all the axes get bigger. I don't understand why.

In that tutorial that tutor opened something. following him I installed that addon.

Later I realized it's for showing the keyboard/mouse buttons.

Is that the reason for this mess? I need that small axis Like I had earlier.

I noticed now <kbd>G</kbd> is moving the origin point, not the entire object!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like you've enabled the Affect Only Origins in the Options panel (top right of 3D view). As for the addon, you can simply deactivate it

Comment: What I should do to stop/get rid of  it?

Comment: have you checked the Options panel?

Comment: origins, locations, parents are ticked (Check the image please)

Comment: should I untick them all?

Comment: yes by default it should be unchecked

Comment: Thank you so much. I must have done it unwittingly. I unticked all. never knew this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've enabled the *Affect Only Origins* option in the *Options* panel (top right of 3D view), this option allows you to change the position of the origin, disable it.